# when query by index in Neo4j, partial results get NaN lucene score

Tags: java, neo4j, lucene

In neo4j, I use custom analyzer to build lucene index. However, when search in index, some of the query result get a NaN score.

source code:

```
try (Transaction tx = Neo4j.graphDb.beginTx()) {
        IndexManager index = Neo4j.graphDb.index();
        /**query*/
        Index<Node> addressNodeFullTextIndex = index.forNodes("NodeFullTextIndex",
                MapUtil.stringMap(IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene", "analyzer", IKAnalyzer5x.class.getName()));
        Query test = IKQueryParser.parseMultiField(fields, query);
        IndexHits<Node> foundNodes = addressNodeFullTextIndex.query(test);

        for(Node n : foundNodes){
            Map<String, Object> m = n.getAllProperties();
            m.put("score", foundNodes.currentScore());
            log.info("method[selectByIndex] score<"+foundNodes.currentScore()+">");
            ret.add(m);

        }
        tx.success();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("method[selectByIndex] fields<"+Joiner.on(",").join(fields)+"> query<"+query+">", e);
        throw e;
    }
```

and that's the result json:

`[
   {
      "score":4.786232,
      "knowledge_name":"信阳市科学技术局",
      "knowledge_id":"baidubaike_4658797/4658797"
   },
   {
      "score":1.4323579,
      "knowledge_name":"信阳市人事局",
      "knowledge_id":"baidubaike_4658842/4658842"
   },
   {
      "score":NaN,
      "knowledge_name":"信阳市农业局",
      "knowledge_id":"baidubaike_4658885/4658885"
   }
]`

neo4j version: 3.1.0
Lucene version: 5.5.0

you can see some score code get a NaN value, why? Or is there something wrong in the query code?